# Does closing the D3 launcher reset download progress?

Tags: diablo-iii

Basically what the title says.  It's taking forever for me to download the latest Diablo 3 update, and I'm wondering if I refresh the connection to perhaps get some better speeds, will I be throwing away the portion of the update that I've already downloaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, your progress so far will not be discarded.  I verified this myself, I was at the same percentage before and after closing and relaunching the launcher.

Comment: This is shared across all newer Blizzard games and their launchers, including World of Warcraft and Starcraft 2 thus far.

Comment: The joys of torrent-based game installers!